# How to store single chars in a twodimensional char array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, casting, char

I simply want to create an array which holds "arrays which hold single chars". 
So I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
char *field[20][20];
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){ //makes blank 2d field with spaces only
        for(int j=0;j<20;j++){
            field[i][j]=" ";
        }
    }

    //debug field visualisation
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<20;j++){
                    printf("%c",field[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");            
        }

        return 1;
}
```

But strangely I get "D" instead of " " as an output for every field element:

```
    DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
    DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
    DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
    DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
    DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
    DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
    DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
    DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
    DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
    DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
    DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
    DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
    DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
    DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
    DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
    DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
    DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
    DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
    DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
    DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
```

Why is that ? I think maybe it's because if some strange casting problems or because of poiters, I'm lost. Thanks !

Comment: @Blaze No your comment is wrong!! , `field`  is a two dimensional array of **`pointers`**

Comment: Oh wow, the `printf("%c",field[i][j])` tripped me up, and of course the title saying it's a twodimensional char array. In that case it should be `%s`.

Comment: Are you getting any warning on statement `printf("%c",field[i][j]);` ?

Comment: @Blaze I would rather look at the definition.

Comment: I am voting to reopen because this close reason does not make sense for this question. The question only asks about one problem.

Comment: `char *field[20][20];` is 2D array of char pointers and supposed to be just 2D char array like `char field[20][20]`

Answer (score 1):

`char *field[20][20];` this is a two dimensional array of pointers to char (aka strings), not a two dimensional array of characters.

`printf("%c",field[i][j]);` This leads to Undefined Behavior because you use `%c` to print a string as I've said `field[i][j]` is of type `char *` and not `char`. Please turn up your compiler warnings and don't ignore them. This mistake should have been flagged by your compiler.

Once you change your code to 2d array of chars everything should work properly:

```
char field[20][20];

// ...

field[i][j] = ' ';
//            ^
//            notice we assign char and not string
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a 20x20 Field Array with char *, so char Arrays (similar to strings).
If you really want to store only chars in that array, change

```
char *field[20][20];
```

to

```
char field[20][20];
```

Then, when initializing your Array, change

```
field[i][j]=" "
```

in line 7 to

```
field[i][j]=' '
```

With " " you are storing char arrays, with ' ' only chars.

This chould fix your issue.